# MySQL Security permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions

Is it possible in MySQL to block users from executing these statements?

```
DESC "table"
SHOW TABLES
SHOW CREATE TABLE "table"
```

Or I need to write a MySQL transport port wrapper ?

`GRANT ON TABLE` does not help to hide database structure from a user.
I want my developers to not be allowed of dumping database structure and `show tables name`

The configuration file: `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
skip-show-database
skip-networking
bind-address=127.0.0.1
#skip-show-tables
#skip-table-stucture-show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I am about to say would be rather crazy but entirely possible. Here it goes...

#### CRAZY SUGGESTION #1

- [**Download the source code for the mysql client**](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.6&o=other)
- Remove the commands

  - `DESC "table"`
  - `SHOW TABLES`
  - `SHOW CREATE TABLE "table"`
- Compile the source
- Give your developers access to this special compiled version of the mysql client

#### CRAZY SUGGESTION #2

- [**Download MySQL Proxy**](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/)
- Program the LUA scripts to ignore

  - `DESC "table"`
  - `SHOW TABLES`
  - `SHOW CREATE TABLE "table"`
- Have your developers access DB using MySQL-Proxy-based IP Addresses

## EPILOGUE

I would say `Give it a Try`, but I have never done anything like this before.

Notwithstanding, it would be a brave C/C++ or LUA soul indeed to engage in such an undertaking...

Comment: Crazy suggestion 1b (download and compile the mysql server)? I mean for 1 to work, you'll have to restrict their access to the Internet so they don't get another client, restrict command line access, not allow PHPMyAdmin install (or restrict use), whatever that can be connected should be removed.

Comment: @ypercube and call it YourSQL !!!

Comment: Just wow. It just might work...

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW TABLE` is implied by `SELECT` because `SELECT` means you need to see the table structure. So it can't be blocked. The same applies for `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

`DESC` = `DESCRIBE` = `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` anyway, which is the same.

So no, it can't be done via MySQL Permissions if you want the developers to run queries